# if variable twig on symfony

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like to do a test on the values ​​selected by the select tag multiple. I tried with this code, but I get this error:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in AdminBlogBundle:GestionGraph:graphkpi1.html.twig at line 575

```
{% for liste in Col1_Array %}
    {% if {{liste}} is "Call Drop" %}
     <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
    {% else %}
      <div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Who can help me please?

Answer (score 10):

You can't nest delimeters like that.

Correct syntax would be:

```
{% if liste == "Call Drop" %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Fairly sure your line:

```
{% if {{liste}} is "Call Drop" %}
```

Should be:

```
{% if liste is "Call Drop" %}
```

Comment: even if I drop call list == I can not find the graphs and if I do I have the two graphs      <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>       <div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

Comment: hello if I tried to, but I have nothing 
{% for liste in Col1_Array %}
{% if liste == "Call Drop" %}
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

 {% else %}
   <div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
      {% endif %}

   {% endfor %}but if I put everything works 
{% for liste in Col1_Array %}
{% if liste == "Call Drop" %}
  <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

      {% endif %}
   <div id="chartdiv1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>

   {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{ dump(liste) }}
```

to find out what really is being evaluated.