# String replace in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have this code:

```
{% set foto = 'photo_gallery/' ~ {{ image.id }} ~ '/' %}
{% set thumbs = 'photo_gallery/thumbs/' ~ {{ image.id }} ~ '/' %}


<img src="{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.mainUrl }}{{ image.image |replace({foto: thumbs}) }}">
```

This is give me error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{". in ......
```

How repair it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if variable twig on symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587738/if-variable-twig-on-symfony)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicate from this : [if variable twig on symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587738/if-variable-twig-on-symfony)

Remember to check deeply on the forum before adding a question :)

Correct code would be :

```
{% set foto = 'photo_gallery/' ~ image.id ~ '/' %}
{% set thumbs = 'photo_gallery/thumbs/' ~ image.id ~ '/' %}


<img src="{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.mainUrl }}{{ image.image |replace({foto: thumbs}) }}">
```

In twig, {% %} represent and execution, meaning what's inside will **do** something. When you are in those tags, you don't need to use {{ }} because twig will be able to interpret your variable names as long as they are not quoted.

More examples and details here : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working :( I have this code: {% set foto = 'photo_gallery/' ~ image.id ~ '/' %}
{% set thumbs = 'photo_gallery/' ~ image.id ~ '/thumbs/' %}.    <img src="{{ pageTemplate.pageHeader.mainUrl }}{{ image.image |replace({foto: thumbs}) }}">. In foto I have this: photo_gallery/240/ and in thumbs I have this: photo_gallery/244/thumbs/

Comment: You validated the answer after saying it was not, what's your status ? :)

Answer (score 0):

In Twig you have to enclose expressions in parentheses to use them as keys. Try this:

```
{{ image.image |replace({(foto): thumbs}) }}
```

Otherwise the key is going to be 'foto' and of course the replace is going to fail.

See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#literals.